# Doing serialization in c++

Tags: c++

I was reading this page about serialization in c++.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialize-binary-format.html
Third bullet got me confused (the one that starts with: "If the binary data might get read by a different computer than the one that wrote it, be very careful about endian issues (little-endian vs. big-endian) and sizeof issues") which also mentions:  "header file that contains machine dependencies (I usually call it `machine.h`)".

What are these endiannes and sizeof issues? (`sizeof` probably being that on one machine `int` can be 4 bytes while on another for example less bytes right?).

How would that `machine.h` file look like?

Is there some tutorial on internet which explains all these things, in an understandable way?

Sometimes in some source codes I also encounter typedefs like:

```
typedef unsigned long long      u64_t;
```

is it related somehow to that `machine.h` file?

Comment: Is [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/) helpful?

Comment: I'll have a look thanks

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 3):

*sizeof*: on one architecture `long` is 64 bits on another 32 bits.

*endianness*: let's assume that 4-byte long. The 4 bytes can be placed in different order in memory, say on intel the least significant bits are at the lowest address, on motorola or sparc the order is the opposite, but there can be processors with 2301 order too.

Comment: Another way to think of endianness is that it's like whether a language writes from left-to-right or right-to-left. It's like deciding whether one thousand is written 1000 or 0001.  As for your `u64_t` typedef, modern C defines a `<stdint.h>` header which defines integer types with known widths. In this case you'd use `uint64_t` for a 64-bit unsigned integer. This fills the role of the `machine.h` file, which is an earlier, non-portable convention.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: Hi Mike, yes maybe someone could explain to me then why this person has done typedefs like the one I showed above? (e.g., u64_t)? why not just use `int`, `long` etc. ps. this typedef I encountered in some other file, not "machine.h"

Comment: Because the C standard itself says little about the actual sizes of those types. I have seen: `short` is 1 or 2 bytes, `int` is 1, 2, or 4 bytes, `long` is 2, 4, or 8 bytes. So these types say *nothing* about the number of bytes on whatever architecture the compiler is targeting. Thus, modern C requires architectures to provide `<stdint.h>` with declared-size typedefs as above. You could provide your own typedefs (like this author did), and prior to `<stdint.h>` this was the only way, but then you had to make sure they were correct for every platform you built on, which was a pain.

Comment: BTW, there's no requirement that `char` be 8 bits, either; the TI TMS5xxx DSP architecture only had 16-bit addressable memory, so pointers pointed to 16-bit values; `char` and `short` were 16 bit and `int` and `long` were 32 bit. `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == 1` and `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) == 2`. Not a fun architecture to write a serial driver for: you had to either add extra code to pack two characters at a time into a `char` or waste the upper half of each memory location.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: there are minimum requirements on ranges what will not allow short and int with 1 (8-bit) byte. though I heard there are platforms where sizeof all integrals is 1 and CHAR_BITS is 36

Comment: @ Mike DeSimone: Yes but how does the same author for example by writing `typedef int                     s32_t;` enforce that this s32_t will have 4 bytes? if this varies across architectures?

Comment: @pseudonym_127: those typedefs are placed in #if sections, and possibly another part of code has static_assert or other checking code to verify. The author must make it right "manually". If the stdint.h header is present it's easier, if you aim exactly for those

Comment: @Balog Pal: Hmm.. I didn't see any #ifs - in the authors code. But you suggest those #ifs should check which architecture we are compiling for etc.?

Comment: if you aim a single platform, no #if is okay. alternative tech uses same file and patches it on checkout. Also can create multiple files and use #if to #include the proper one

Comment: @BalogPal: Doesn't change the fact that I've seen some C compilers (not gcc) for 8-bit targets set `int` to 8 bits and `long` to 16. They probably weren't standard-conforming (though they may have conformed to K&R C; things were pretty loose in the 80's), but they existed. The platform you speak of sounds typical of a DSP, which only have one word size.